# Solutions for simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve the following system of equations:

$ac-5bd=5$

$ad+bc=0$

So far I've managed to find (I'll put it as in {$a,b,c,d$}):

{$0,-1,0,1$}

{$0,1,0,-1$}

{$5,0,1,0$}

Comment: Solve any pair in terms of the other: There is infinitely many solutions. You want integers maybe? Generally, to have a unique solution to a system of $n$ variables you need $n$ equations. But this is not always the case, even in $\mathbb{R}$: $(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2=0$ only has one solution.

Comment: Yes, I mean $a,b,c,d$ are integers. I should have specified!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c=0$. Then $ad=0$. Therefore either $a$ or $d$ are $0$. From the first equation, $c,d$ can't be zero simultaneously, so $a=0$. But then $bd=-1$ It is easy to see from the factorizations the the only solutions are then $\{0,-1,0,1\}$, $\{0,1,0,-1\}$

If $a$ is zero, then we would also have $c=0$, yielding the same solutions. Suppose that $a,c\neq0$ hereafter.

If $d=0$ from the second equation $b=0$. So $ac=5$. Here, you actually missed some solutions (and accidentally repeated one:) )

Comment: Yes, I've just edited that out! How silly of me! :)